# Decoding named ranges as Tables from excel files in JavaScript, React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, excel, xlsx, sheetjs

I was working on a project which is dealing with excel manipulation and creating JSON(s) based on the data getting from excel. There is a number of named ranges in excel (Including named ranges as tables as well as by specifying the range). We are currently using the React version of SheetJS (xlsx) which was helpful to decode the named ranges when the range was specified. But we are unable to find the range when the named range was specified as tables (eg: `Table3[[#All],[Prior Country Location]]`). Any help will be greatly appreciated. Any existing workarounds or different plugins are welcome.

Thanks in advance